# converting jQuery script for div id to loop div classes

Tags: jquery, class, loops, click, hover

The script below applies random colours from an array to a div id, and changes the colours on hover.  I would like to amend it so that it loops through a div class and applies random colours to all classes on a page.  Obviously the click functions would have to be done by id, but I imagine there is a way of looping through the div classes such that they all have different random colours which change on hover.

Could someone help with this?

Thanks

Nick

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var test = $("#example").text().split('');

    var normal = generateColors(test);
    var hover = generateColors(test);
    $("#example").html(normal);

    $("#example").hover( 
      function(event) { $("#example").html(hover) }, 
      function(event) { $("#example").html(normal) });

    $("#example").click(function() { 
    location.href = "http://www.google.co.uk"; 
    });

});

function generateColors(characters) {
    var result = "";
    var i = 0;
    for(i=0; i < characters.length; i++) {
        result += "<span style='color:"+getColor()+"'>"+characters[i]+"</span>";
    }

   return result;
}        

function getColor() {
    var colList = ['#7EA404', '#14AFB0','#B05718', '#B0A914', '#B01617','#902BB0', '#B003A2', '#4A429C','#33821E', '#226795', '#D0B600','#886833'];

    var i = Math.floor((Math.random()*colList.length));
  return colList[i];
}
```

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To apply the colors, and store them on the different elements, you could do:

```
$(".example").each(function() {
    var text = $(this).text().split(''),
        normal = generateColors(text),
        hover = generateColors(text);

    $(this).html(normal).data('hover', hover).data('normal', normal);
});

$(".example").hover( 
    function() {
        $(this).html($(this).data('hover'));
    }, 
    function() { 
        $(this).html($(this).data('normal'));
});
```

Setting each link with location.href on click seems like a really bad idea, but up to you.

Comment: Thanks, that's just what I was looking for.  The reason I was setting the links with jQuery was that hrefs within a div weren't working.  I now realise though that if I add the class "example" to the a link it works.  Thanks!

Comment: Yes, you can use `<a>` elements instead, and it will work just the same, as you've now realised. Happy to help !

Answer (score 0):

> Obviously the click functions would have to be done by id

I'm not sure why that would be.

You can apply a click function to jQuery array of objects via a class if you'd like:

```
$('.myDivs').click(...)
```

Comment: If the URLs are different for each div?

Comment: are you assigning urls to each individual div via jQuery? I'd suggest storing the urls in data-* attributes, but I'm not entirely sure what you're goal is.

Comment: That is the method I was using, as you can see above, with the single DIV id.  I am simply looking to apply to the colour effects to a number of DIVs/links on a page.  The randomised colour effect would be the same, but each would link to a different page.

Comment: Split the logic. Assign URLs via one function, then assign the random colors via another. For the random colors, just give every div the same class and retrieve them all via class.

Answer (score -2):

are you looking for something like

```
$('div').each(function(){
  //code
})
```

Comment: Low quality & not very targeted to answer the question as asked. (too generic)